# PowerView automatically aggregating data

Tags: excel-2013, powerview

I have several fields in a SQL Server Table that are Integer but are labels.  When I try to bring the data into PowerView for Excel it automatically aggregates these numbers and gives me an aggregate with a Sigma showing they are a sum.

How do you change this?

I am new to PowerView and this is kind of annoying.  I don't want to bring the data in as a table as it is over 1 million rows.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power View will automatically aggregate numbers, there are two options to prevent this. In the Power View field well fields can be set to 'do no aggregate', alternatively fields can be prevented by aggregating at all via the Power Pivot window.

Do not summarize via the field well

[image: Do not summarize via the field well]

Do not summarize via Power Pivot

[image: Do not summarize via Power Pivot]